# Help Text not showing on <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocksectionitem

I have a table inside of a pageblocksection and then inside of that I have an  that I am trying to utilize the default help text for but it's not showing up.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
  <apex:outputPanel>
    <table> width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="test text">
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!searchBySKU}" />
            <apex:outputLabel value="Search for this SKU or text in the SKU name" />
          </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work as I expect?

EDIT:

So, I just did some more testing and it creates the text if it's a direct child of the pageBlockSection. Is there any way to get around this restriction without going the fully custom route to do so?

Comment: just get rid of outputPanel to make it direct child ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava O wow that actually worked.  I sort of needed the outputpanels for rerendering... but I can get around that.  Thanks.  Post that as an answer and I can accept.

Comment: Workaround can be use outputPanel at outer or inner blocks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the outputPanel to make it direct child of pageblockSection

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
<table> width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="test text">
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!searchBySKU}" />
        <apex:outputLabel value="Search for this SKU or text in the SKU name" />
      </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Mohith Shrivastava, the same i we just tried, i have <apex:pageBlockSectionItem> direct child of <apex:pageblockSection>. the help text does't work.